# mod-rewrite with apache 2.4 and CentOs 7 don't replace index.php in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vagrant, httpd.conf, centos7

Have a Vagrantbox with centos 7 and apache 2.4. In /var/www/html have a Codeigniter PHP Site with pretty-url rewrite. I create the vm with puphpet config.yaml. The VM is running correct, VM-server is running correct, mode_rewrite ist activ and allowed to all, but i try a url like this:

```
http://codeigniter.dev/home ->file not found
http://codeigniter.dev/index.php/home -> site ok
```

There is no way to replace index.php, don't know why?
On my Server with Centos and apache this configrution runs perfect, but in my VM it didn't replace?!?

Here are my Configs:

**puphpet/config.yaml**

```
vagrantfile:
    target: local
    vm:
        provider:
            local:
                box: puphpet/centos7-x64
                box_url: puphpet/centos7-x64
                box_version: '0'
                chosen_virtualizer: virtualbox
                virtualizers:
                    virtualbox:
                        modifyvm:
                            natdnshostresolver1: false
                        showgui: 0
                    vmware:
                        numvcpus: 1
                    parallels:
                        linked_clone: 0
                        check_guest_tools: 0
                        update_guest_tools: 0
                machines:
                    vflm_via243h8nsof:
                        id: codeigniter
                        hostname: codeigniter.dev.local
                        network:
                            private_network: 192.168.56.101
                            forwarded_port:
                                vflmnfp_57zntu84qm8k:
                                    host: '9583'
                                    guest: '22'
                        memory: '2048'
                        cpus: '1'
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet/manifests
                module_path:
                    - puphpet/puppet/modules
                    - puphpet/puppet/manifests
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
        synced_folder:
            vflsf_f72ykqm374hd:
                source: ./
                target: /var/www
                sync_type: default
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                    mount_options:
                        dir_mode: '0775'
                        file_mode: '0664'
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
        post_up_message: ''
    ssh:
        host: 'false'
        port: 'false'
        private_key_path: 'false'
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: 'false'
        keep_alive: '1'
        forward_agent: 'false'
        forward_x11: 'false'
        shell: 'bash -l'
        insert_key: 'false'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
    proxy:
        http: ''
        https: ''
        ftp: ''
        no_proxy: ''
server:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups:
        - www-data
    users:
        - www-data
locale:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_locale: de_DE.UTF-8
        locales:
            - en_GB.UTF-8
            - en_US.UTF-8
        timezone: Europe/Berlin
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: 2.4
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - proxy_fcgi
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        av_myrx1sclhqnx:
            servername: codeigniter.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.codeigniter.dev
            docroot: /var/www/html
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            setenvif:
                - 'Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1'
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_6sroj6oyuexi:
                    path: /var/www/html
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_o1gz78z6saqx:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: ''
                            provider: filesmatch
                    provider: directory
letsencrypt:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        email: admin@codeigniter.dev
    domains: {  }
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '7.1'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - xml
        pear: {  }
        pecl: {  }
    ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_jncm5era33zg:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions:
        rv_dpiw29f3bvhv:
            default: '1'
            bundler: '1'
            version: 2.3.1
            gems:
                - deep_merge@1.0.1
                - activesupport@4.2.6
                - vine@0.2
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '6'
    npm_packages: {  }
mysql:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '5.7'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mysqlnu_r5di0ad1ifk2:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mysqlnd_k34jv21bgnjk:
            name: codeigniter
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mysqlng_rn6tn59qj8nf:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**VM/ /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

```
# Security
ServerTokens OS
ServerSignature On
TraceEnable On

ServerName "codeigniter.dev.local"
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
PidFile run/httpd.pid
Timeout 120
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
LimitRequestFieldSize 8190


User www-data
Group www-data

<Directory /var/www/html>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>


HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
LogLevel warn
EnableSendfile Off

#Listen 80


Include "/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/*.load"
Include "/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/*.conf"
Include "/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf"

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" forwarded
```

I read a lot of posting for this problem, but no solution, so i hope to get some help here.

Comment: I would make sure .htaccess is really under /var/www/html. Or otherwise disable AllowOverride altogether and add those rewrite rules inside the Directory tag (which will have the same effect without the added overhead of making the server having to look for that file several times each hit). Another tip, Use Require all granted/denied instead of Order/Allow/Deny directives if you use 2.4.

Comment: .htaccess is in root dir (var/www/html), thats not the problem, i tested the htaccess, it is running. The "Order/Allow/Deny" was a mistake  from me when i copy/paste code. In my httpd.conf is "Require all granted" standing but server do not rewrite url. I#m not shure that this httpd.conf is the right file to edit. In the Centos manual is they talking about a /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf. Thanks for your response..